# R is changing locale settings on it's own initiative

Tags: r, utf-8

I'm having the problem that R is changing the locale settings every now and then spontaneously. I cant reproduce (trigger) the problem, but symptoms are listed below. Why is this happening, and how can it be avoided?

When running various code, R suddenly stop the execution and provides error messages like:
`Error in nchar(x) : invalid multibyte string, element 1`
When this happens, it seems the locale has been changed, since `Sys.getlocale()` do not provide the correct locale settings:

```
Sys.getlocale()' 
'[1] "C"
```

Then running `Sys.setlocale()` restores the session to the default (and correct) locale:

```
Sys.setlocale() 
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_CTYPE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_MONETARY=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8"
```

The error messages shows up when there are nordic letters (e.g. "ø") in code or data, but it seems the changing locale settings is triggerd by other things and that the symptoms are showing up when the nordic letters are in code or data.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                             LC_TIME=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Oslo
tzcode source: internal
```

Comment: Something else strange is going on.  My responses are different. `Sys.getlocale()` returns a single string `[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"` rather than multiple array elements.  I'm on MacOs, R4.3.1  .   However, it appears that your locale isn't being "changed" but rather **clobbered** if all that got returned was that string `C`  .